# Decomposition rule relational databases

Tags: database, inference, decomposition

I got a relational database of type R={A,B,C,D,E,F} with functional dependencies like 
F = {{AB-->C}; {A-->D}; {D-->AE}; {E-->F}}

However, with help of inference rules I have come up with the statement BD-->ABCEF , I wonder if it is allowed with decomposition rule to eliminate the B from the right side?

The decomposition rule says:

> If X --> YZ then X --> Y and X --> Z

Basically is BD --> ACEF correct?

Comment: Furthermore, if you have (BD) and (AB) as candidate keys and someone asks for the primary key, are both candidate keys arbitrary for primary key?

Answer (score 1):

Yes: AB->CDEF, BD->ACEF.

> are both candidate keys arbitrary for primary key?

Correct. There is no formal basis for choosing a primary key and primary keys have no significance in dependency theory anyway.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply! Further question:
When you in the next step are supposed to decompose R in 2NF (second normal form, where no nonprime attributes should be functionally dependent on a part of a candidate key) are you then only looking at the given functional dependencies or abstract dependencies from implied inference rules as well?

> e.g. Does A-->CDEF violates the definition of 2NF? 

> (Where A-->CDEF is decomposed from AB-->CDEF)

Comment: In normalization you consider the closure of all dependencies - the given ones and those derived from them. How did you arrive at A->CDEF though? AB->CDEF does not imply A->CDEF.

Comment: I took from F{..}: (AB-->C)=>(A-->C) ; (A-->D)&(A-->C)=>(A-->CD); from (D-->AE) to (D-->E) with (E-->F) gives (D-->EF) then finally given (A-->CDEF). I do not really know if that is correct?

Comment: AB->C does not imply A->C. See Armstrong's rules. http://tinman.cs.gsu.edu/~raj/4710/sp08/fd-theory.pdf